# Puzzled over memory leaks in MFC project that disappear if _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() is never called

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-leaks, mfc, visual-studio-2017

I have an MFC (C++) dialog-based project that is compiled with Visual Studio 2017. I've added the following code to track for possible memory leaks as I build it:

From within `ProjectName.cpp` before my `CWinApp`-derived class is initialized.

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <Wtsapi32.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Wtsapi32.lib")


struct CatchMemLeaks{
    CatchMemLeaks()
    {
        HANDLE ghDebugLogFile = ::CreateFile(L".\\dbg_output.txt", 
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
            NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

        //Enable logging into that file
        _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
        _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE | _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE));
        _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_WARN, ghDebugLogFile);
        _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE | _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE));
        _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ERROR, ghDebugLogFile);
        _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE | _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE));
        _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ASSERT, ghDebugLogFile);


        //Try to break on the error reported
        _CrtSetBreakAlloc(75);
    }

    ~CatchMemLeaks()
    {
        if(_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks())
        {
            DWORD dwRespMsgBx;
            ::WTSSendMessage(NULL, ::WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(),
                L"MemLeak", lstrlen(L"MemLeak") * sizeof(WCHAR), 
                L"MemLeak", lstrlen(L"MemLeak") * sizeof(WCHAR),
                MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR | MB_SYSTEMMODAL,
                0, &dwRespMsgBx, TRUE);
        }
    }
};

CatchMemLeaks cml;



//Then the usual MFC CWinApp-app derived class stuff:
// CProjectNameApp

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CProjectNameApp, CWinApp)
    ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP, &CWinApp::OnHelp)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CProjectNameApp construction

CProjectNameApp::CProjectNameApp()
{
    // support Restart Manager
    m_dwRestartManagerSupportFlags = AFX_RESTART_MANAGER_SUPPORT_RESTART;

    // TODO: add construction code here,
    // Place all significant initialization in InitInstance
}


// The one and only CProjectNameApp object

CProjectNameApp theApp;

//....
```

Then when the project runs and then exits, I'm getting my `WTSSendMessage` triggered:

[image]

Which gives me the following output:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{75} normal block at 0x0000029BA5EA75D0, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <   G            > B0 86 D0 47 F7 7F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{74} normal block at 0x0000029BA5ECE930, 48 bytes long.
 Data: <0       0       > 30 E9 EC A5 9B 02 00 00 30 E9 EC A5 9B 02 00 00 
{73} normal block at 0x0000029BA5EA82F0, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <p  G            > 70 86 D0 47 F7 7F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{72} normal block at 0x0000029BA5ECEA80, 48 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 80 EA EC A5 9B 02 00 00 80 EA EC A5 9B 02 00 00 
{71} normal block at 0x0000029BA5EA8070, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <   G            > 20 86 D0 47 F7 7F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{70} normal block at 0x0000029BA5E98BA0, 120 bytes long.
 Data: <                > A0 8B E9 A5 9B 02 00 00 A0 8B E9 A5 9B 02 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

But then on the next debug run, when I add the `_CrtSetBreakAlloc(75);` line showed in the code above, the breakpoint on error `75` never triggers, although the output still remains the same.

Then another interesting discovery is that if I remove the `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` function from my `~CatchMemLeaks` destructor, those memory leaks go away.

PS. I know that this is something peculiar for this particular project because I don't get the same behavior if I try it with a stock MFC-dialog-based app.

Any idea how to track where those leaks are coming from?

Comment: I can't duplicate the leak. You haven't shown a full MCVE. Also use `CWinAppEx` instead of `CWinApp`, that can make a difference when using frame windows.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Oh, wait, I just realized it. Thanks. The class was derived from `CWinApp`. I didn't change it since MFC wizzard created it. Although now when I text-replaced `CWinApp` to `CWinAppEx`, I'm getting an assertion in `CShellManager` constructor on this line `ENSURE(afxShellManager == NULL);`. Do you have any idea how can I set that `afxShellManager`? This may be my problem.

Comment: OK, found what was causing the `ENSURE(afxShellManager == NULL)` assertion. MFC had this line in `InitInstance()` that was triggering it if I replaced `CWinApp` onto `CWinAppEx`: `CShellManager *pShellManager = new CShellManager;` Commenting it out removes the assertion. I don't know what it does but it didn't "like" `CWinAppEx`-derived class. Still, unfortunately this doesn't solve the original issue....

Comment: And again about your duplicating the issue. I can't do it either in a stock project. That's what makes is challenging....

Comment: use how minimum `#pragma init_seg(compiler )` before `CatchMemLeaks cml;` for `cml` constructed the first in exe and destructed last

Comment: `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks` can report false leaks if you are using old libraries. Or maybe you have heap corruption. Put deliberate leak at the start of your program `new char[123];` and note its allocation order. Is it less than 70 or greater than 75? (compared to allocation orders listed above)

Comment: @RbMm: If I add that `#pragma init_seg(compiler)` line the app crashes somewhere in `CWinApp` destructor on `_AFX_THREAD_STATE* pState = _afxThreadState;` line before my own destructor is called.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Hah, good idea! I added `new int[1];` right after the `_CrtSetBreakAlloc(75);` line in my code above, and the output had this line added to it: `{76} normal block at 0x000001A251064F00, 4 bytes long. Data: <    > CD CD CD CD`. And if I then do `_CrtSetBreakAlloc(76);`, it breaks on that `new` operator. So what does it mean?

Comment: I am not sure, but it looks like there was a leak before any of your own code was executed, maybe caused by another library, or maybe there is heap corruption and you are getting inaccurate report.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: I tried running my process with [`PROCESS_CREATION_MITIGATION_POLICY_HEAP_TERMINATE_ALWAYS_ON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/overview-of-threat-mitigations-in-windows-10) to check for heap corruption and it didn't trigger it.

Comment: I think I got it! Details are in a separate answer. @RbMm gave me the clue. Thanks, dude!

Answer (score 3):

Oh shoot, I got it. (Thanks to [@RbMm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6401656/rbmm) in the comments!) The catch is to make this leak detecting code initialize before (and un-initialize after) all other CRT and MFC constructors and other stuff. The trick is to use `#pragma init_seg(compiler)` directive. My original mistake was to use it in the `.cpp` file where the `CWinApp`-derived class was defined. That caused a crash when the app was exiting because that `#pragma` directive applies to the entire `.cpp` file.

So the solution is to create a separate `.h` and `.cpp` files for my `CatchMemLeaks` class and set that `#pragma` directive there, as such:

`CatchMemLeaks.h` file:

```
#pragma once

//Only debugger builds
#ifdef _DEBUG

#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <crtdbg.h>  

#include <Strsafe.h>
#include <Wtsapi32.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Wtsapi32.lib")


struct CatchMemLeaks{
CatchMemLeaks(int nMemLeakCodeToCatch);
~CatchMemLeaks();
};

#endif
```

and `CatchMemLeaks.cpp` file:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "CatchMemLeaks.h"

//Only debugger builds
#ifdef _DEBUG

#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 4074)
#pragma init_seg(compiler)      //Make this code execute before any other code in this project (including other static constructors).
                                //This will also make its destructors run last.
                                //WARNING: Because of this do not call any CRT functions from this .cpp file!
#pragma warning( pop )

CatchMemLeaks cml(0);       //Set to (0) to monitor memory leaks, or to any other value to break on a specific leak number




CatchMemLeaks::CatchMemLeaks(int nMemLeakNumberToBreakOn)
{
    HANDLE ghDebugLogFile = ::CreateFile(.\\dbg_output.txt, 
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
        NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    //Enable logging into that file
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE | _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE));
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_WARN, ghDebugLogFile);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE | _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE));
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ERROR, ghDebugLogFile);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE | _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE));
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ASSERT, ghDebugLogFile);

    if(nMemLeakNumberToBreakOn)
    {
        _CrtSetBreakAlloc(nMemLeakNumberToBreakOn);
    }
}

CatchMemLeaks::~CatchMemLeaks()
{
    //Dump memory leaks, if any
    if(_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks())
    {
            DWORD dwRespMsgBx;
            ::WTSSendMessage(NULL, ::WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(),
                L"MemLeak", lstrlen(L"MemLeak") * sizeof(WCHAR), 
                L"MemLeak", lstrlen(L"MemLeak") * sizeof(WCHAR),
                MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR | MB_SYSTEMMODAL,
                0, &dwRespMsgBx, TRUE);
    }
}

#endif
```

then lastly include it in the `stdafx.h` file:

```
#include "CatchMemLeaks.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely that your `CatchMemLeaks` class is created and then destroyed before all other objects in your program are cleaned up, so in effect you're reporting a false-positive (the other objects will get cleaned up after)

But it's hard to tell without a fully running program.

Comment: Well, that's the whole idea to do this before and after all objects are created and are supposed to be released. I'm trying to catch memory leaks. Still this doesn't explain why this works in a stock MFC project.

Comment: MFC has a bunch of static and global variables that are objects whose lifetime scope is beyond "code".