# _CrtSetBreakAlloc using memory contents and not the allocation number

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, mfc, visual-studio-2017, crt

I'm using [`_CrtSetBreakAlloc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/crtsetbreakalloc?view=vs-2017) function to track down memory leaks in `debugger` builds of my MFC project. ([Here's the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54121021/843732) from my previous question.)

That technique works for as long as the `Allocation order number` remains the same. But in many cases it does not. For instance, here's two reports that I'm getting now:

First run:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{222861} normal block at 0x000002BDF58347C0, 240 bytes long.
 Data: <C : \ P r o g r > 43 00 3A 00 5C 00 50 00 72 00 6F 00 67 00 72 00 
{222860} normal block at 0x000002BDEFBA52A0, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <                > 10 AF B7 EF BD 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{222859} normal block at 0x000002BDEFB7AF10, 40 bytes long.
 Data: < R       G      > A0 52 BA EF BD 02 00 00 C0 47 83 F5 BD 02 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

Second run:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{222422} normal block at 0x00000123DDB67540, 224 bytes long.
 Data: <C : \ P r o g r > 43 00 3A 00 5C 00 50 00 72 00 6F 00 67 00 72 00 
{222419} normal block at 0x00000123DDBA9C50, 16 bytes long.
 Data: <    #           > 80 16 B7 DD 23 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{222418} normal block at 0x00000123DDB71680, 40 bytes long.
 Data: <P   #   @u  #   > 50 9C BA DD 23 01 00 00 40 75 B6 DD 23 01 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

So I'm wondering, if there's a function, or a way to rewrite `_CrtSetBreakAlloc` to make it trigger a breakpoint on the memory contents? For instance, in my case, when the memory gets Unicode-16 string `"C:\Progr"` written into it.

Comment: Does overloading new as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library?view=vs-2017) help any?

Comment: @PhilM: Idk, I'll need to try it.

Comment: I'm guessing the path is a CString, so knowing the file/line for that allocation might not be too useful. But it might help with the other blocks.

Comment: They're 3 consecutive allocations, where the 2nd one has a pointer to the first (as the first thing in the block), and the 3rd appears to be a file name or path.  The first block (lowest numbered) has pointers to the other two blocks.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a `_CrtSetAllocHook`. But how should this help? The data is set AFTER the allocation. So no hook will take place when the data you want to trigger is written into the memory allocated.

The only way I see is to use `_CrtDoForAllClientObjects` and search through all allocated blocks.

Comment: Hmm. I'm assuming [this is an example](https://github.com/Microsoft/VCSamples/blob/master/VC2008Samples/crt/dfacobjs/DFACOBJS.C) how to use it. So what you're suggesting is to enumerate and locate the memory block at the process exit when the leak is being reported, right?